# ng-model to a multiple select in angulardart

Tags: dart, angular-dart, django-autocomplete-light

I am trying to use `ng-model` with a multiple select in angulardart. The select is dynamically populated with `option` by `django-autocomplete-light`. Once I have added a few options, my (list) model is still empty.

Any point I could look at?

Here is a minimal example.

Template:

```dart
 <span id="id_car-wrapper"
   class="modern-style autocomplete-light-widget"
   data-widget-bootstrap="normal"
   data-widget-maximum-values="4" data-widget-ready="1">
      <span id="id_expert-deck" class="deck"></span>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="car-autocomplete"
        id="id_car-autocomplete" value=""
        class="autocomplete"
        data-autocomplete-choice-selector="[data-value]"
        data-autocomplete-minimum-characters="1"
        data-autocomplete-url="/autocomplete/CarAutocomplete/"
        placeholder="car's name" autocomplete="off">

      <select style="display: none" class="value-select"
        name="cars" id="id_expert" multiple="multiple"
        ng-model="myctrl.cars"></select>
```

Controller:

```dart
@NgController(
    selector: '[a-selector]',
    publishAs: 'myctrl')
class MyController {
    List<String> cars;
}
```

**Edit:** according to Günter's answer, I wrote this directive:

```dart
  @NgDirective(selector: 'select[multiple]')
  class MultipleSelectDirective {
    SelectElement _selectElement;
    Compiler _compiler;
    Injector _injector;
    DirectiveMap _directiveMap;

    MultipleSelectDirective(Element this._selectElement, this._injector, this._compiler, this._directiveMap) {
      _selectElement.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted',
          (_) => _compiler(_selectElement.childNodes, _directiveMap)(_injector, _selectElement.childNodes));
      _selectElement.addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved',
          (_) => _compiler(_selectElement.childNodes, _directiveMap)(_injector, _selectElement.childNodes));
    }  
  }
```

Comment: Can you create a minimal example to reproduce the issue? Controller and HTML markup and add this to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended doing it by inspecting the DOM from Dart each time it is updated:

```dart
@NgDirective(selector: 'select[multiple][ng-model]')
class MultipleSelectDirective {
  SelectElement _selectElement;
  NgModel ngModel;
  Scope scope;

  MultipleSelectDirective(Element this._selectElement, this.ngModel, this.scope) {
    _selectElement.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted',
        (_) => _setValue());
    _selectElement.addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved',
        (_) => _setValue());
  }

  void _setValue() {
    List<OptionElement> options = _selectElement.selectedOptions;
    List val = [];
    options.forEach((o) => val.add(o.value));
    ngModel.viewValue = val;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this myself yet but the Angular.js API doc seems to use it differently.

`ng-model` holds the selected value and `ng-options="myctrl.cars"` assigns the items.

I would expect Angular.dart to work similar.

This worked for me:

```dart
<div a-selector>
  <select multiple="multiple" ng-model='myctrl.selected'>
    <option ng-repeat='c in myctrl.cars'>{{f}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

You need to add a field to the controller where you can assign the selected items (I used `myctrl.selected`) which receives a `List<String>`.

**EDIT**

When the HTML is modified you have to compile it to make Angular process the new elements and directives.

```dart
static dom.NodeValidator validator;
dom.Element _element;
Compiler _compiler;
Injector _injector;
DirectiveMap _directiveMap;
MyController(this._element, this._injector, this._compiler, this._directiveMap) {

_compiler(_element.childNodes, _directiveMap)(_injector, _element.childNodes);
```

I think a better way would be to try to get the values from JavaScript to Dart and add them to you controller and let `ng-repeat` insert them.

Comment: Nop, Angulardart has dropped support for ``ng-options``. Unfortunately I cannot find again the reference .

Comment: Then I would expect to require ng-repeat. I try to create a working example.

Comment: The point is, I don't know the available cars in advance since I get a filtered list via a REST api. That's why my ``select`` is empty, I know how to populate it given an existing dart list.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. When you get values somewhere you fill `myctrl.cars` with these values and `ng-repeat` will take care of the rest.

Comment: Does `django-autocomplete-light` generate the options without the knowledge of Angular?

Comment: Yes it's an independent jQuery plugin

Comment: I tried to call the compiler from an event listener registered by a directive, but this doesn't work (the event listener correctly fires). Does the compiler have to be called from a controller?

Comment: I think this shouldn't matter. Maybe the problem is when you run the compiler on an element where is was already run. I use this code to make Angular process dynamically generated/added HTML but `_compiler()` is only called once per element. Can you add your code to your question to show how you tried to use it?